# Non-interactively ssh to server but interactively

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh, sh, ssh-keys

I understand all the security risks using ssh in this way, but what I need at the moment is a few line (bash) shell script capable to log-in to the `target` server and just do a foo command and get back to the source host, something like:

```
while true
do
   ssh target foo   # Here I get the prompt for a password which
                    # I would like to give non-interactively
   sleep 1
done
```

I **do not want** to use the ssh key based authentication because what I truly need is to simulate once a second (or so) the interactive log-in process (but not-interactively!).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to script it with `expect` in something like, say, [perl](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod).

**Edit:** You could also try scripting `expect` directly in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780893/725163).

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the SSH server to allow login based only on a key and not from a password.

Try to see if [this](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html) can help you.

Of course if you can't edit the server configuration, you need to check other solutions

Answer (score 0):

[sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) is designed to provide a password to ssh programatically, instead of interactively.  So you can replace `ssh target foo` by e.g. `sshpass -f passwordfile ssh target foo`.