# linux pipe with multiple programs asking for user input

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I wonder how to create a pipe

```
program 1 | ... | program N
```

where multiple of the programs ask for user input. The problem is that `|` starts the programs in parallel and thus they start reading from the terminal in parallel.

For such cases it would be useful to have a pipe `|` that starts program (i+1) only after program i has produced some output.

**Edit:**

Example:

```
cat /dev/sda | bzip2 | gpg -c | ssh user@host 'cat > backup'
```

Here both `gpg -c` as well as `ssh` ask for a password.

A workaround for this particular example would be the creation of ssh key pairs, but this is not possible on every system, and I was wondering whether there is a general solution. 
Also gpg allows for the passphrase to be passed as command line argument, but this is not suggested for security reasons.

Comment: Once you connect a program to a pipe, it gets its input from another program, not the user. Are you sure you want a pipe? I can't really think of a program that both takes user input *and* reads from standard input.

Comment: Not an answer, but an idea which may point you in the right direction:  Could you include code around each program to check the output for a particular string, updating a flag once found and have the other calls loop until the previous program's flag were updated, then allow them to run?

Comment: Show a specific example of this happening. A program could read from `stdin` and from `/dev/tty`, but this would be unusual.

Comment: @chepner: no, not always, program can read from `tty` also. And the case in the question is exact such case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction:

```
(read a; echo "$a"; cat) > file
```

For example:

```
$ (read a; echo "$a"; echo cat is started > /dev/stderr; cat) > file
1
cat is started
2
3
```

Here `1`, `2` and `3` were entered from keyboard; `cat is started` was written by echo.

Contents of `file` after execution of the command:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am now using:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "I am root!"
sudo cat /dev/disk0 | bzip2 | gpg -c | (read -n 1 a; (echo -n "$a"; cat) | ssh user@host 'cat > backup')
```

The first `sudo` will prevent the second from asking the password again. As suggested above, the `read` postpones the starting of ssh. I used `-n 1` for `read` since I don't want to wait for newline, and `-n` for `echo` to surpress the newline.

Comment: `sudo -v` will extend the timeout, prompting for the password if you haven't been validated at all yet. This lets you avoid having to come up with an extraneous command (`echo "I am root!"`) to run.

Answer (score 0):

for one you can give gpg the password with the `--passphrase` option.

For ssh the *best* solution would be to login by key. But if you need to do by password the `expect` command will be good. Here's a good example: [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Expect also allows you to have some input - so if you don't want to hardcode your passwords this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed something similar a few times before, where the first command in the pipeline requires a password to be entered, and the next command doesn't automatically cater for this (like the way that `less` does).

Similar to Igor's response, I find the use of read inside a subshell useful:

```
cmd1 | ( read; cat - | cmd2 )
```