# ssh-copy id and expect in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I am making auto-pass with expect in bash.The code is;

```
ssh-copy-id -i $SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP (here asks pass)

VAR=$(expect -c" 
     expect "*?assword:*"
     send "$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD\r";
     send -- "\r"
     expect eof
     ")

echo "$VAR"
```

It still asks password.what is the problem

SOLVED: ssh-copy-id -i $SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP must be in expect block as;

```
spawn ssh-copy-id -i $SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP
```

and the line

```
 send "$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD\r";
```

must be

```
send \"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD\r\";
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command?rq=1)

Comment: Why not use key based authentication?

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR=$(expect -c "expect '' \
  {eval spawn \
  ssh-copy-id -i $SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP; \
  interact -o -nobuffer -re .*assword.* return; \
  send "$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD\r"; send -- "\r"; \
  expect eof;} ")

echo "$VAR"
```