# sudo command in Popen

Tags: python

I want to run sudo command from within my python module and provide the password inside the python code. Here are my unsuccessful attempts:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'make', 'install'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print output.communicate('mypass\n')
```

It asks password from console window (Then I do not want). Then I tried:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'make', 'install'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output.stdin.write('mypass\n')
output.stdin.close()
output.wait()
```

Again it asks password. Then I tried:

```
os.popen("sudo make install", 'w').write('mypass')
```

It again asks for password.
What's wrong with my code. I tried all above attempt after doing some search in internet and it seems like they should work.

Answer (score 2):

sudo, ssh, sftp are all designed to know if there is a tty attached, so they ask for a password.  The reason is that putting passwords in code is a big security violation.

You can use the expect utility to run sudo or ssh and your python code, too...

[Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Comment: I am not going to write password in my code. User will enter his password from a GUI. So you want to say that above three attempts might work for other commands other than sudo. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add an entry to /etc/sudoers for the particular command and the particular user.

```
builduser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/make
```

Edit: It's probably better to wrap the particular command you want in a script, and then allow them sudo access to the script w/o a password; obviously 'make' is fairly dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

To add user interactivity you should use `pexpect` (http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) rather than popen. This will allow your program to to run sudo properly.

Keeping passwords in your script is always a bad idea and allowing access via modification to sudoer especially for something like `make` is a security hole.