# Interact with serial device with shell scripting

Tags: shell, serial-port, usb, tty

I have a serial usb device that is connected to a linux box and it works fine with serial communication programs, such as minicom.
For instance, within that program, I send the string "V" and I get back an answer: "UBW FW D Version 1.4.3".

Now, I'd like to do a shell script that could do the same, in order to test variables. I investigated the possibility to use minicom without being "interactive" but it seems is not possible. I also tried the obvious "echo V > /dev/ttyACM0" but had no luck as well.

Any idea of how can I send and receive strings to/from a serial device in such way I can use the received data in a shell script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the olden days of modems, we would use the program 'expect' to send and receive data from the serial line. This doesn't exactly solve your problem, but might get you some of the way there.

Have a look at [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Answer (score 0):

The [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program does exactly what you are asking for. Example:

```
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 -
AT
OK
$
```

Now, from you example command and response, I see that your "modem" seems to able to [configure](http://www.schmalzhaus.com/UBW/Doc/FirmwareDDocumentation_v143.html) or [modify](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?t=10980) to not return the `OK` Final Result Code, and atinout absolutely needs that for its operation, so make sure the UBW behaves properly.