# Bash script to push ssh_keys

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to read a file with the names of approx 500 server names on their own individual lines, and then for each of those, ssh in and append the roots `authorized_keys` file for each. I keep getting errors each time I run the script and/or modify it. Can you please help me figure out what's wrong? My OS is Mac OS X:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 60
set SERVERS "cat /Users/macuser/server.lst"
set USER "myuser"
set MY_PASS "mypasswordhere"

for EACH in $SERVERS; do
cat /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $USER@$EACH "tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys"
expect {
    eof                          {break}
    "The authenticity of host"   {send "yes\r"}
    "password:"                  {send "$MY_PASS\r"}
    }

interact
done
```

here is the error:

```
wrong # args: should be "for start test next command"
while executing
"for EACH in $SERVERS"
(file "./keyssh_push.sh" line 7)
```

Comment: what errors do you see?

Comment: Would `ssh-copy-id` be what you're looking for?

Comment: @glennjackman im not sure, im not familiar with that command. I put the errors above.

Comment: @user102825 `ssh-copy-id` is bundled in the OpenSSH package. What it does is exactly what you are trying to script. The only piece you would need to write is the expect where passing the password is done or use sshpass as suggested by graeme. See my comment in graeme's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command), `sshpass` looks like the easiest way to do this. I would do:

```
#!/bin/sh
servers=`cat /Users/macuser/server.lst`
user="myuser"
my_pass="mypasswordhere"

for server in $servers
do
  </Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sshpass -p"$my_pass" \
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$server cat '>>.ssh/authorized_keys'
done
```

#### Update

With @alvits's suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh
servers=`cat /Users/macuser/server.lst`
user="myuser"
my_pass="mypasswordhere"

for server in $servers
do
  sshpass -p"$my_pass" ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$server
done
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what i originally started with. i was trying to use "expect" because most of the servers that im connecting to arent in my known_hosts file so each time i get prompted to save with a "(yes/no)?". i was trying to avoid that. is there a way to script in the "yes" to the known_hosts and the password prompt?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts

Comment: You mean like `/usr/bin/yes` ?

Comment: Updated answer to disable StrictHostKeyChecking, although using `ssh-keygen`/`ssh-keyscan` to add keys to known_hosts before starting is a safer approach.

Comment: Why don't you use `sshpass -p"$my_pass" ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/macuser/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$server`? This will also ensure the remote user's .ssh directory is created if it doesn't exist.