# Bash Script - SSH Connection

Tags: bash, ssh

I am having difficulty passing a password through a bash script for an ssh connection. I have everything working, but it still prompts me for the password instead of pulling the stored password. Please take a look at the portion of the script below, and let me know if there is something obvious I'm doing wrong:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Please enter a username:"
read user
echo "please enter a password:"
read password
echo please enter an IP address:"
read ip

ssh "$user"@"$ip"
expect "password:"
send "<password>\r"
interact
```

I have tried different variations of the "send" line. For instance, I've tried "password\r" and password\r. I've also tried modifying the "expect" line to mirror the exact text returned by the attempted SSH connection.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command

Answer (score 1):

SSH contains code to prevent password theft by redirecting standard I/O.

The correct solution is to generate a private/public key pair with `ssh-keygen`. Install the public key on the remote side. `ssh-copy-id` will help.

Then you can use the SSH agent to load the private key into memory and SSH won't ask for a password or key phrase.

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login