# Docker [ENTER] flag

Tags: shell, docker, command-line, dockerfile, flags

I am currently writing a Dockerfile, and I one of the commands I want to execute requires the user to press [ENTER], for example:

```
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
```

I know that on some commands when it requires a `[Y/n]` the `-y` flag will suffice; however, in some commands such as this one, it requires a physical key press. Therefore, I would like you to please help me solve this issue.

How does one send a [ENTER] key press as a flag in a Dockerfile?

Comment: http://core.tcl.tk/expect/index

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to add a prompt during the docker build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432712/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-prompt-during-the-docker-build-process)