# bash making decisions on returned values

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, expect

I have a script which goes and finds a username, password  and IP address from a keepass database (kpcli) and have a variable $ssh_info that returns output to 3 lines like this

```
bobuser
bobpassword
bobip
```

what's the best way for me in a bash script to then say take the results of the $ssh_info

```
ssh bobuser@bobip and then use expect to send the password
```

Something like

```
echo "$2"  (bobpassword)
ssh $1@$3  (ssh bobuser@bobip)
```

Or even an expect script that passes the $2 (bobpassword) into the ssh $1@$3

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command

Comment: Are you asking how to split the variable into the various fields? Are you asking how to use `expect` to send the password to `ssh`? Are you asking something else?

Comment: Are you asking how to split the variable into the various fields? Yes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're thinking of?

```
expect <<END_EXPECT
    lassign [split "$ssh_info" \n] user pw ip
    ssh \$user@\$ip
    expect "assword:"
    send -- "\$pw\r"
    interact
END_EXPECT
```

That uses the shell variable `$ssh_info`. The Tcl variables require a backslash to hide them from the shell.

If you want to split the multi-line string in the shell, I'd do one of

```
{ read user; read pw; read ip; } <<<"$ssh_info"
mapfile -t info <<<"$ssh_info"  # then use ${info[0]}, ${info[1]}, ${info[2]}
```