# SCP using Expect Spawn comand in Linux

Tags: linux, directory, scp, spawn

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set login "root"
set addr "10.10.10.10"
set pw "123!"

set localDir "/home/user/www/*"
set servDir "/var/www/html/"



spawn scp -r $localDir $login@$addr:$servDir
expect "connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\r"
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
interact
```

I need to copy all the files in /home/user/www/ to /var/www/html/ but when I run the SCP command in SPAWN using the directory string /home/user/www/* it gives an error.

Running it as /home/user/www/ doesn't but it copies the www folder straight off which is not what I need to happen.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION A:**

The **best** way is to set up password-less log-in. It is not a good idea to throw your password naked on the network. Once the auth keys are set up, you can use `scp` without password prompts,or even in a `crontab`.

First log in on Sys_A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys. Do not enter a passphrase:

```
a@Sys_A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
```

Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on Sys_B. (The directory may already exist, which is fine):

```
a@Sys_A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
b@Sys_B's password:
```

Finally append a's new public key to b@Sys_B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last time:

```
a@Sys_A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
b@Sys_B's password:
```

From now on you can log into Sys_B as b from Sys_A as a without password:

a@Sys_A:~> ssh b@Sys_B

**OPTION B**

Use `expect` .

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com
#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_password\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_command1\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_command2\r"
interact
```

Sample solution for bash could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com; interact }'
```

This will wait for enter and than return (for a moment) interactive session.

Please see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Comment: I understand the risk of having the password naked outside. But my issue lies because this line will not execute: `spawn scp -r /home/user/www/* root@10.10.10.10:/var/www/html/`

Comment: What is the error your are receiving? Also try `cd /home/user/www` and
`spawn scp -r . root@10.10.10.10:/var/www/html/` . Mark the `.` after `spawn scp -r`