# Run bash script inside the expect script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, expect

Im trying to run my bash script inside an expect script but getting errors.

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh nginubud@10.123.25.83 $(< try1.sh)
expect "assword:"
send "$reg\r"
expect eof
EOD
```

im trying to do this in expect `ssh nginubud@10.123.25.83 "$(< try1.sh)"`, this one is working but i need to find a way to run it in automated way. I dont want to use RSA keys.

error that in encountered:

```
spawn ssh nginubud@10.123.25.83 #tats script
invalid command name "echo"
    while executing
"echo "Enter Year:""
```

Also i can run my expect ssh script but when i include and try to run my `$(< try1.sh)` im getting "no variable errors"

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com; interact }' `

how can I insert this line (ssh nginubud@10.123.25.83 "$(< try1.sh)" ). Im trying to run the try1.sh script from machine 1 to remote machine 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ssh user@host bash -c ...`. For example:

```
[bash] % cat foo.sh
export CMD=$( printf '%q' "$(< try.sh)" )
expect << EOF
spawn ssh foo@localhost bash -c \$::env(CMD)
expect -nocase password:
send bar\r
expect eof
EOF
[bash] % cat try.sh
echo hello world | tr a-z A-Z
[bash] % bash foo.sh
spawn ssh foo@localhost bash -c echo\ hello\ world\ \|\ tr\ a-z\ A-Z
foo@localhost's password:
HELLO WORLD
[bash] %
```

Comment: Thanks sir. this is a working method but my script has some input and i cant input anything, script run thru without a prompt of input

`Enter Year:
Number of Entered Days : echo


Details :
Year:   Month   Days 
echo "Enter Month:"     echo "How many days?"      

Please wait while generating output . . .


done !`

Comment: Hi Sir it only prompt the first input then `Enter Year:
2015
[bash]$ 2015
-bash: 2015: command not found`

Comment: Please provide more details (your scripts, error messages, debug output, ...). Open a new question if it's not easy to put in the comments.