# How to execute shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How to execute the shell scipt?

When I ran my script using:

```
jalaj@jalaj-SVF14212SNB sudo ./startvpn.sh  
[sudo] password for jalaj: 
sudo: unable to execute ./startvpn.sh: Permission denied //It says
```

When I execute this using 
    sudo sh  startvpn.sh 
    [sudo] password for jalaj:

```
I get the output as 

startvpn.sh: 2: startvpn.sh: spawn: not found
startvpn.sh: 3: startvpn.sh: expect: not found
startvpn.sh: 4: startvpn.sh: expect: not found
startvpn.sh: 5: startvpn.sh: interact: not found
```

Below is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn openconnect --no-cert-check 103.194.44.2
expect -exact "Username:"send -- "XYX\n"
expect -exact "Password:"send -- "XYX%"
interact
```

I checked the above permission using

```
-rwxrw---x 1 jalaj jalaj 168 Aug 10 12:29 startvpn.sh
```

It say users `jalaj` can execute but I am not able to execute.
Can anyone guide me how to execute the script?

Comment: You do not need `sudo` to execute the script. remove it

Comment: @Jens Then only it says the same output

Comment: Do you have `expect` installed?

Comment: can you Show your script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure `expect` is actually installed:

***Debian-like:***

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

***RedHat-like:***

```
sudo yum install expect
```

Then you might want to use `sudo` to execute your script.

---

Check this previously asked question as well: ["Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780893/4000674)