# Can't get bash script to answer prompt with expect

Tags: bash, shell, expect

My ssh access is restricted to a Google Authenticator verification code prompt. I'd like to have a script that programmatically answers that prompt.

**Context**:

- The variable 
  ($1) passes correctly to the script - it's the verification code.
- The sshfs command works in terminal.
- The prompt `Verification code:` comes with space and a key symbol at the end.

[EDIT] Just to make sure we don't switch to security discussions here, please note that of course **I also use SSH keys, additionally to this Google Authenticator**. As the Authenticator **verification code expires every x seconds** it does not matter that others could intercept it.

**Result**:

The disk mounts (I can see it with `df -h`), but is empty... Kind of same behavior as when the Verification code is wrong, or maybe it doesn't have the time to execute?

**Shell script**:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    expect_sh=$(expect -c "
        spawn /usr/local/bin/sshfs username@123.123.1.123:/path/to/folder/RAID1 /Users/username/Desktop/RAID1 -o defer_permissions -o volname=RAID1
        expect \"Verification code:\"
        send \"$1\r\";
    ")

    echo "$expect_sh"
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you see `Verification code:` in `$expect_sh`?

Comment: Thx @EmilyE. , how would you echo inside expect_sh in order to verify this  plz?

Comment: Wondering does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @EmilyE. Unfortunately not. In the meantime, I can confirm that the variable goes trough as I had `send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "432941\r""` when deactivating authenticator. Currently, the script executes, I can see the commands and Verification code: that get executed but then nothing, no mounted volume, no error message. How could I expect anything? Maybe it's because Verification code comes with a space after it, and a key symbol?

Comment: Have a look [there: Trying to get SSH with public key (no password) + google authenticator working on...](https://serverfault.com/a/632197/142978)

Comment: @F.Hauri Why do you send me there? Did you even read the description of my issue?

Comment: I'm trying to help: *using `expect` with `ssh` is a wrong good idea*! Nota `ssh` and `sftp` use direct `tty` dialog for passwords! Not regular `STDIO`! This could be an issue with `expect`.

Comment: Have you tried simple sleep before delivering your passkey? You could also try using sshpass.

Answer (score 3):

#### I'm afraid, I have to answer *no*.

There are some issues:

1. Having password has argument could reveal your password to other users with a simple

   ```
   ps axw
   ```
2. Having password stored into a variable could reveal your password to other users with a simple

   ```
   ps axeww
   ```
3. Having passord transmited via *`STDIN`* could be easy to trace.

For this and a lot of other reason, `ssh` (and `sftp`) refuse to trasnsmit secrets via arguments, variables or *`STDIO`*.

Before asking for password, there is a lot of verification, then the use of a secured dialog (working with direct TTY or with some boxes on X DISPLAY).

So using `expect` or passing secret as arguments is not directly possible with `ssh`.

But.

You could connect `ssh` server by using secret key:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:q/2fX/Hello/World/Lorem/Ipsum/Dolor/Sit/Amet user@localhst
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|          .=o=E.o|
|      .. o= o    |
|     o+ +=...    |
|     .o+ o+o.    |
|   . +.oS.oo     |
|  . *.= .  ...   |
|   o =.     oo.  |
|  ...        +o. |
| .ooo       oooo.|
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Then now, you have to send your `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to be stored in `authorized_keys` file in the server you try to connect to (this files is located in `$HOME/.ssh/` or in `/etc`, but could be located elsewhere, depending on `sshd.conf` in server).

Comment: Thanks for your security concerns but unfortunately that's out of the question's context. Of course I use ssh additionally to the Google Authenticator verification code.

Comment: The thing is: because of this security concerns, regular tools like `ssh` and `sftp` are built in a way that make use of standard redirection not possible for secrets.

Comment: Did you alreasy read [this answer to: Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780893/1765658)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this isn't working is that you are running `expect` in a subshell inside the command substitution.

This would be a regular harmless [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) if it weren't for the fact that you hope and expect the process to remain alive.

Just take out the variable capture and run `expect` as a direct descendant of your current script.  If you *really* require your output to be available as a variable when it's done, maybe try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

t=$(mktemp -t gauthssh.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT ERROR INT HUP TERM  # clean up temp file when done
expect -c "
    spawn /usr/local/bin/sshfs username@123.123.1.123:/path/to/folder/RAID1 /Users/username/Desktop/RAID1 -o defer_permissions -o volname=RAID1
    expect \"Verification code:\"
    send \"$1\r\";
" | tee "$t"
expect_sh=$(<"$t")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems very interesting, I'll try this asap and accept the answer that works.

Comment: You're welcome, but I fail to see how this comment is useful or necessary. If you *don't* plan to do that maybe we would need to know.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that it may take a couple of days so I wanted to show my gratitude instead of silence... cheers

Comment: The bounty ends in 12 hours so you really need to get that done within a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a solution with screen(1)

I tested the script below.  It's not especially robust, and
you'll need to make some changes according to your enviroment.

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -d -m -S sshtest sh -c "ssh -l postgres localhost id > output"

pass="77c94046"
ret="$(printf '\n')"

while true; do
        screen -S sshtest -X hardcopy
        grep -q 'password:' hardcopy.0 && break
        sleep 1
done

grep -v '^$' hardcopy.0
echo -n "$passenter" | xxd
screen -S sshtest -X stuff "$pass"
screen -S sshtest -X stuff "$(printf '\r')"
sleep 1
cat output
```

The idea is to set up a screen running your command that redirects
its output to a local file.  Then you take screen grabs in a loop and
look for your expected prompt with grep.  Once you find it, use the
'stuff' command in screen to push your password into the terminal
input (i.e. screen's pty).  Then you wait a bit and collect your
output if needed.  This is just proof of concept code, a robust
solution would do more error checking and cleanup, and wait for
the screen to actually exit.

Comment: Thank you for this different approach, I'll try this asap.

Comment: Yes, or with `xdotool` you can emulate mouse and keyboard events... (but, please, don't!)