# Script run locally but fail on Jenkins (Got SIGTERM, exiting)

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, expect, sigterm

I'm trying to run a script from jenkins (with using expect) - The script run correctly while I'm trying to run it from a jenkins slave locally.
However, when I trigger a job to run it, the script fails and throws an error of:

```
11:05:47 the_user@ip.ip.ip.ip's password: Got SIGTERM, exiting
11:05:47 In exit
```

The script :

```
local_path=reports/
remote_path=/nfsserver
admin_user=my_user
admin_password=my_password
folder_to_copy='orion'_$(date '+%F_%H_%M')

cp -r $local_path $folder_to_copy
expect -c "
spawn scp -r $folder_to_copy/ admin_user@10.247.141.144:$remote_path
expect {
    #expecting to get sign-on on an unssinged server
    "*connecting*"
        {
        send "yes"\r;exp_continue
        }
        #expecting to get promt to enter password for scp
        "*password:*"
         {
         send $admin_password\r;interact
         }
    }
exit
    "
rm -rf $folder_to_copy

fi
```

can you please aid?

EDIT:
Tried changing the password to hard-codded value, with and without brackets - nothing worked.

EDIT2:
Tried replacing **expect** with **sshpass** but it failed on the same error.

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command. Maybe a good hint there?

Comment: Tried, didn't succeeded finding anything..