# Combining SSH commands

Tags: ssh

so far I use a two step ssh tunnelling.

```
ssh -X username@server.de

ssh -KX your_pc_name
```

Is it possible to combine those two commands into one command? For different applications I need something like

```
ssh -options user@server.de
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), maybe will help you. You can create a script that runs commands on the remote machine. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783182/1977955) answer.