# Why does ssh find -exec does not work in script?

Tags: shell, ssh, find, exec, expect

I need to use a find command in a script with ssh and find together. Something like this:

```
expect -c "
    spawn ssh user@host \"find api -type f -name *.html -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;\"
    expect {
        \"*password\" {set timeout 300; send \"mypassword\r\";}
          }
    expect eof"
```

And I get

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any thoughts on what may be causing this or how I can fix it ? Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Comment: You should rewrite your script as suggested above, because your way you will need to replace `\;` by `\\\;`

Comment: @meuh, only need 2 backslashes. or use single quotes to protect the semicolon.

Comment: @meuh You are right.  It works . Thank you very much .

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

I find heredocs to be helpful to avoid quoting hell

```
expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    spawn ssh user@host "find api -type f -name *.html -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;"
    expect "*password" {set timeout 300; send "mypassword\r"}
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```