# Is there a way to simulate Save and Close a file through shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a scenario where a shell script runs another shell script. The second shell script prompts user to type review comments and close the file.

In my case, I do not want to type anything but only save and quit (equivalent vim command `:wq`) the file. I want to automate this through a shell script where I don't want manual intervention to save and quit the file. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783182/5868851)

Comment: Did you try something like `echo ":wq" | vi file` ? Depending on the second script this might fail and you need smething like `expect` (see link of @Zelnes).

Comment: provide an example of your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure i get the context but if you simply (echo "input of your choice" >> file.txt ) it will do the job and will not have to quit and save anything
if th einput is already in a file you can (cat inputfile.txt >> file.txt )
this command can be place inside of your first script