# script to connect to a "list.txt" of servers

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

I am trying to find a way to connect to a list of servers written in a simple textfile to run one command and write the output to a file...
The small problem is, I have to login with a password... but it would not a problem to paste the password into the script.
the full command would be:

`ssh "server_from_list.txt uptime | awk -F, '{sub(".*up ",x,$1);print $1}' >> /home/kauk2/uptime.out`

lets assume the password is: abcd1234

Any suggestions??? I am not fit in scripting, sorry...
Many thanks to you all in advance...

regards,
Joerg

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should set up password-less login, but failing that you can use `sshpass`. First, get a single command working by trying the following:

```
export SSHPASS=abcd1234
```

Then you can try:

```
sshpass -e ssh user@server1 'uname -a'
```

When you get that debugged and working, you can use **GNU Parallel** to run the command on all servers in a file called `list.txt`

```
user@server1
user@server2
user@server3
user@server4
```

The command will be:

```
parallel -k -a list.txt sshpass -e ssh {} 'uptime'
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
thanks for your suggestion. I forgot to say, I am working in an IBM AIX environment. So, no sshpass is available here...