# Expect script not working and terminal closes immediately

Tags: authentication, ssh, terminal, expect

I don't know what's wrong with the script. I set up a new profile on Iterm terminal to run the script, but it never works and closes immediately. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 120
set secret mysecret
set username asdf
set host {123.456.789.010}
set password password123
log_user 0

spawn oathtool --totp --base32 $secret
expect -re \\d+
sleep 400
set otp $expect_out(0,string)

spawn ssh -2 $username@$host
expect "*assword:*"
send "$password\n"
expect "Enter Google Authenticator code:"
send "$otp\n"
interact
```

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, test you ssh connection with:

```
ssh -v <auser>@<apassword>
```

That will validate the SSH session works.
Make sure to not use `ssh -T ...`, since you might need a terminal for [`expect` commands](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/) to work.

Second, add at least an `echo` at the beginning of the script, to see if it is called:

```
puts "Script running\r"
```

Third, see if a bash script, with [part of it using expect as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783182/6309), would work better in this case

Comment: @glennjackman I meant using the expect command which is the equivalent of `echo`, since it is an expect script, not a bash script. So yes: puts.