# Bash script to execute Java console application

Tags: java, bash

I have a Java console application which accepts the user input and performs action based on the input. Below is the sample:

```
**Payout Table          Multiplier**
=======================================
Royal Flush     |       250
Straight Flush  |       50
Four of a Kind  |       25
Full House      |       9
Flush           |       6
Straight        |       5
Three of a Kind |       3
Two Pairs       |       2
Royal Pair      |       1

-----------------------------------
Balance: $500
Enter bet:
```

I have to enter the amount to bet with:

```
Enter bet: 300

HAND: [K Spades, J Spades, 10 Clubs, 9 Diamonds, J Hearts]  
Enter positions of cards to keep (e.g. 1 4 5):

Enter positions of cards to keep (e.g. 1 4 5):  
3

Held Cards: [10 Clubs]  
NEW HAND: [10 Clubs, 5 Clubs, 10 Hearts, A Diamonds, 10 Diamonds]

**Three of a Kind**

Your balance: $1400  
One more game (y or n)?

y
```

I just need help with an idea of a bash script to automate this manual process.

Comment: The point of a console app is generally that the user will interact with the app. How about passing arguments via command line to a non console application instead?

Comment: You mean, you're asking how to **pipe** input to the program (using `|` or `<` in the script) to answer the prompts, rather than letting user enter the information? How would the script know what to answer on the second prompt, given that the cards are random?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the different cases that you would like to enter, you might be able to use `expect`:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Example for a similar problem:
[Use Expect in a Bash script to provide a password to an SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command)

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn java Main

# May need to adjust prompts to match better
interact -o -nobuffer -re "Enter bet: " return
send "300\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re "Enter positions of cards to keep (e.g. 1 4 5):\r" return
send "3\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re "One more game (y or n)?" return
send "y\r"
interact
```