# Simple script does not work with os.system

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to create and assign a password for a user in Linux, but it gives an error:

```
New password: Retype new password: Sorry, passwords do not match
```

Here is the script (executing with root):

```
from os import system
system('useradd user')
system('echo -e "pass\npass\n" | passwd user')
```

Comment: I wrote some script like 2 months ago everything was working fine besides if you execute the same commands in bash password changes successfully, now I opened it and this error occurred, no idea what's the problem and how to fix it

Comment: Try to separate the `system` calls by the `\n` like this: `system("echo -e pass")` and then again `system("echo -e pass")`.

Comment: It needs to be executed simultaneously with ```passwd```

Comment: Try to use [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command) if its possible. Or try `\r` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

God damn it :) So tried debugging for some reason echo returned -e pass\n on the first try. Removed -e argument completely so it's `system('echo "pass\npass\n" | passwd user')` and it's working now.

Comment: `-e` should be fine. If `echo` actually outputs the _-e_, I would conclude that you didn't pick up the "right" echo. What happens if you go back to your original code, but explicitly invoke `/usr/bin/echo -e ....`?

Comment: You are right ```/usr/bin/echo -e``` works too.

Comment: If this would be my platform, I would investigate some time to find out **which** `echo` you are executing. My feeling is that you are running dash and use the `echo` which is built into it.

Comment: I ran it on several OS with the same result so that's why it was bugging me.