# How to execute commands right after login using SSH connection? But after few seconds of login, it disconnect me from remote server

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash 
 expect <<END
        spawn ssh -o user@remote_ip
        expect "password"   
        send "my_pass\r"
        expect eof
    END
    cd /var/www/html/node_project/
    ##npm init -y
    npm install
    ##node index.js
```

I want run some commands right after login into remote server. I can login successfully, but 2 or 3 seconds later, it automatically logout me from the remote server. How can I make it wait until all of my commands run and execute successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Expect in a Bash script to provide a password to an SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command)

Comment: No,  I want everything to be automated. @Jetchisel

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS "sleep 10 ; ls -l"
```

or this (for connection timeout):

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS 'nohup bash -c "sleep 3; ls -l"'
```

Note: replace `ls -l` with your command.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution: I have run multiple commands in line and it executes all the commands one after another.

```
spawn ssh user@remote_ip "cd /var/www/html/node_project/" && "npm install" && "node index.js"
```

Comment: This seems to suffer from some serious problems both in formatting and actual contents.